Gmail failing DMARC checkups of domain
The setup
I'm using both PHP mail() function and AWS (PHP SDK) for email sending.
PHP mail() function is used for a cronjob, where I wanted to avoid using AWS, for something fairly simple. The DKIM is sent as part of the headers (I'm adding it manually - hardcoding it).
AWS is used to send emails from a webapp.
DNS records are setup as follows:
DKIM
v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=<DKIM>

DMARC
v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; rua=mailto:no-reply@example.com; ruf=mailto:no-reply@example.com; fo=0; aspf=r; adkim=r

SPF
v=spf1 ip4:<my_server_IPv4> include:amazonses.com +a +mx ~all

The problem
Emails sent via AWS are going to spam, whenever I'm sending to Gmail or Yahoo addresses (not many of those, but I guess the issue is the same). Looking at the raw email message (Gmail option Show original), I see that DMARC is failing, but there's no explanation why.
aspf=r and adkim=r were originally missing from the DMARC setup, and after some googling, I added them to setup a relaxed policy. I thought that this would resolve the spam issue, but I was, apparently, wrong about it.
I know that I can resolve this by simply using AWS everywhere, or better yet, with domain verification (instead of an email verification), but that's not an option at the moment (though it might be later on).
Propagation of DNS changes (SPF, DMARC) doesn't seem to be the issue, since various online services return the correct info when queried.
Is there anything wrong with my setup? Is it even possible to resolve the issue I'm facing with just DNS changes?
